# Aparece error invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: python, funciones, pyqt5, widget, qlineedit

Estoy haciendo un programa en PyQt5 y me arroja el **ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''**

Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)

La espectativa hasta el momento, es que a partir de una señal enviada desde el widget definido como lineEdit_mouse_valor, llegue al slot que llama la función llamada def suma_1(self):

```
def suma_1(self):


    valor_mouse = int(self.ui.lineEdit_mouse_valor.text())

    cantidad_mouse = self.ui.sb_Mouse.value()

    valor_subtotal1 = valor_mouse * cantidad_mouse

    self.ui.lineEdit_mouse_subtotal.setText(str(valor_subtotal1))
```

La función es valida para las primeras operaciones hasta esta linea, luego agrego las otras operaciones que quiero pretender de esta manera:

```
    valor_teclado = self.ui.lineEdit_teclado_valor.text()

    cantidad_teclado = self.ui.sb_teclado.value()

    valor_subtotal2 = valor_teclado * cantidad_teclado

    self.ui.lineEdit_teclado_subtotal.setText(str(valor_subtotal2))
```

pero desafortunadamente me arroja el error, quiero ser afortunado de entender lo que pasa y como solucionarlo, gracias.

Comment: Verifica que lo que reciba sea un número, '1' y no 'mouse` ( estos son ejemplos)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que se está lanzando la ejecución del código y el método `self.ui.lineEdit_mouse_valor.text()` está devolviendo una cadena vacía. (Asumo que es porque el usuario no ha llenado el campo.

Esto se deduce del mensaje de error que te dice, luego del mensaje de error cuál es el valor que se intentó convertir (y falló):

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

El `''` es una cadena vacía.

Puedes manejar la excepción para, por ejemplo, notificar al usuario de su error. El tipo específico de excepción que queremos manejar, nos lo dice también el mensaje, al inicio. En este caso es `ValueError`:

```
def suma_1(self):
    try:
        valor_mouse = int(self.ui.lineEdit_mouse_valor.text())
        cantidad_mouse = self.ui.sb_Mouse.value()
        valor_subtotal1 = valor_mouse * cantidad_mouse
        self.ui.lineEdit_mouse_subtotal.setText(str(valor_subtotal1))
    except ValueError:
        msg = QMessageBox()
        msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Critical)
        msg.setText("Error")
        msg.setInformativeText("No ha introducido un valor válido, introduzca un entero e intente de nuevo")
        msg.setWindowTitle("Error")
        msg.exec_()
```